# Почему я не могу преобразовать тип данных String в тип данных int?

Tags: java, типы-данных, приведение-типов

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = input.next();
System.out.println(answer);

int answer2 = Integer.parseInt(answer); 
System.out.println(answer2);
```

Почему я не могу просто написать:

```
System.out.println((int) answer);
```

Comment: `String` - объект, `int` - простой тип. Из одного простого в другой простой можно скастовать, а с объектами такое не прокатит - в этом случае объект должен быть или того же класса, или каким-то его предком

Comment: Поскольку число НЕ является строкой, кастинг невозможен.  А для преобразования как раз и следует использовать методы класса `Integer`: `parseInt` или `valueOf`.  Также кастинг не нужен `System.out.println(answer);`

Answer (score 0):

- `int` - это примитивный тип данных. В переменной такого типа вы просто храните число. Всё. Это коробка для чисел. Не более.
- `String` - это ссылочный тип данных. Это означает, что переменная такого типа (объект) ссылается на какой-то класс. В данном случае это класс [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Таким образом, на переменную ссылочного типа (объект) можно вызывать методы (команды грубо говоря) или обратиться к полю (к какому-то данному). Поэтому объект можно даже сравнить с роботом.

А теперь задумайтесь: как вы из обычной коробки сделаете сложного робота? Никак. Вот так же из примитивного типа нельзя сделать объект.